# Unable to launch nautilus with sudo

Tags: nautilus, sudo, gksu

When I run Nautilus with `sudo`, `gksudo` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, I get this error message:

```
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

** (nautilus:2352): WARNING **: Failed to get the current CK session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '2352'

(nautilus:2352): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nautilus:2352): CRITICAL **: nautilus_directory_file_monitor_add: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_DIRECTORY (directory)' failed

(nautilus:2352): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:2352): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(nautilus:2352): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:2352): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (nautilus:2352): CRITICAL **: nautilus_directory_get_uri: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_DIRECTORY (directory)' failed
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is everything up to date? Try reinstalling gnome-disk-utility.

Comment: why disk utility?... i reinstall anyway and still same problem.

Comment: Because nautilus-gdu stands for nautilus-gnomediskutility.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [gnome-user-share](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-user-share) and see if that helps.

If Nautilus still doesn't start try [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8871167&postcount=9):

1. Open a terminal (in [Unity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#In%20Unity) or [Gnome](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#In%20Gnome))
2. Then type `sudo mkdir /usr/share/nautilus-scripts`
3. Enter your password and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fix this, there remains a problem with calling nautilus in sudo/gksudo/Open with administrative privileges:

Nautilus will remain in memory even when you close the root window, regardless what command-line options it gets, there is a --no-daemon or --no-fork option missing ever since.

I'd recommend using a different file-manager for root tasks, thunar from xfce for example.